# how to read fields from pipe (|) delimited file with preserving spaces

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I am looking to extract 2 names from a pipe delimited file which looks like below,

```
1|1234|first name|2|56768|second      name   |message
```

my code looks like below,

```
cat $file_name|while read row; do
name1=`echo $row | awk -F\| '{ print $3 }'`
name2=`echo $row | awk -F\| '{ print $6 }'`
echo name1 is $name1
echo name2 is $name2
```

The problem I am facing is above code is removing multiple spaces within the actual data and also removing trailing spaces.

I need to have data as it is e.g. it should keep multiple spaces within data if original data has multiple spaces within it.

can anyone please suggest how can I extract name1 and name2 as above preserving spaces in the data ?

if reading fields by while loop or by awk is not good method then can you please suggest alternative way or perl script way instead of bash ??

Comment: I am not sure why multiple spaces are not showing up here but my data has multiple spaces within it e.g. "second  <space><space>  name  <space><space>   "

Comment: Too see the spaces you need to quote the shell variable in your echo statement:  `echo name1 is "$name1"`.

Comment: If you let us know what you're trying to do at a higher level it almost certainly can be done much more efficiently with a single invocation of awk and no looping in the shell.

Comment: Thanks. here I have shown echo statement just to demonstrate my issue, in reality I am not echoing that name1 variable but using "$name1" to do further processing like greping that name and processing etc. but things are not working when there are spaces within data.

Comment: jas, my file has 10k records so I need to get the names out of it and do some processing by looking into other files. So I need exact data to search into other file due to this I want data as original (with spaces in it (if it has spaces)

Comment: You also need the quotes around `$row`:  `echo "$row" | ...`